# how to give read more link in a block?

Tags: views, blocks, users, entities

I have a views block which display user's detail like name, picture and about.
i want to give a read more link in "about" field, by click "read more" link the trimmed "about" will open in the same block.

"About" is a field from view, so in this field text will trim after 200 words if the about field is more then 200 words then after trimmed part there will be a read more link and after clicking this link the whole text will visible on the same position just increase the height of the block.

Thanks

Comment: where do you want to redirect the user by clicking this button ?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery expander](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_expander) module will work for you.

You will have to select expander from formater options in views field configuration.

Comment: i have install this module and include the library in to libraries/expander folder, and set the formater as expander but its not working.

Comment: show error            (function ($) {

/**
 * jQuery expander.
 */
Drupal.behaviors.jqueryExpander = {
  attach: function (context) {
  
    var expander = Drupal.settings.jqueryExpander;
      // Add the jQuery expander.
      for (var key in expander) {
        $('.field-expander-' + key).expander(expander[key]);//error in this line uncaught
      }
    }
};

})(jQuery);

Comment: I have tested this module before posting it here. See if this is working from manage display for any field

Comment: you may also post this error in drupal.org issue que for this module